# Will closing a DataInputStream also close the FileInputStream?

Tags: java, inputstream

```
FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(someFile.getPath());
DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
```

If i call `in.close()`, will it also close `fstream` ? My code is giving GC Exception as follows:

**java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, `DataInputStream.close()` also closes your `FileInputStream`.

This is because `DataInputStream` inherits `FilterInputStream` which has the following implementation of the `close()` method:

```
    public void close() throws IOException {
        in.close();
    }
```

Comment: BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

Comment: i also have a buffered reader but i do not close it in the end could this be the cause of GC overhead??

Comment: @Ady.Q if your question now is about will BufferedReader.close() close InputStreamReader, answer will be also "yes - it will".

Comment: It's hard to make logical connection between those two facts, but you have to close your BufferedReader after doing reading.

Comment: Thank you so much for the response. I got the point but my code goes as follows

Comment: FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(someFile.getPath());
DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
// Read the file line by line
DataInputStream.close();
// But i do not close the buffered reader.. can this be a potential cause for GC exception..

Comment: @Ady.Q well, actually in some situations it could.

Comment: @Andremoniy could you elaborate why please? Is it that you always have to close the highest level stream even if you close lower level ones before because it does not know if the underlying stream is closed?

Comment: Thanks for answering. Somewhat.. My question was more towards why closing a lower level stream first (or only) could lead to a GC issue. Isn't the underlying resource released and the high level stream can just be GC'ed? Is it because the high level stream can't flush before the rescource being closed?

Comment: @Andremoniy I forgot to mention you

Answer (score 6):

Your `DataOutputStream` inherits its `close()` method from `FilterOutputStream` whose [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FilterOutputStream.html#close%28%29) states that:

> Closes this output stream and **releases any system resources
>   associated with the stream.**
>
> The close method of `FilterOutputStream` calls its flush method, and
>   **then calls the close method of its underlying output stream.**

The same should be true for all `Writer` implementations (although it's not stated in the docs).

---

To avoid running into memory problems when working with Streams in Java, use this pattern:

```
// Just declare the reader/streams, don't open or initialize them!
BufferedReader in = null;
try {
    // Now, initialize them:
    in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
    // 
    // ... Do your work
} finally {
    // Close the Streams here!
    if (in != null){
        try {
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This looks less messy with Java7 because it introduces the [`AutoCloseable`-interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html), which is implemented by all Stream/Writer/Reader classes. See the [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).

Comment: can a closed Reader/Stream opened again? as a seperate question, do you think this pattern can be used in a multi threaded system where each thread wants to access to the same place to read data?

Comment: @OnatKorucu AFAIK streams can't be re-opened. They need to be re-created. As far as multi-threading is concerned, streams are not thread-safe. So if you need to share data between threads, read it in one thread and share that state via a thread-safe collection.