# How do I keep the socket open after the first file transfer so that I can transfer more files in future

Tags: sockets

Below I am sending a file with its name to a client. later i will like to send more files to the same client through the same socket.

Here is my code for server:

```
 BufferedOutputStream out = null;
    try {
        JFileChooser fr = new JFileChooser();
        FileSystemView fw = fr.getFileSystemView();
        String path = fw.getDefaultDirectory() + "\\1 (2).jpg";
        File file = new File(path);
        out = new BufferedOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
        try (DataOutputStream d = new DataOutputStream(out)) {
            d.writeUTF(path);
            Files.copy(file.toPath(), d);
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(App_window.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

and here is code for the client:

```
  BufferedInputStream in = null;
    try {
        in = new BufferedInputStream(server.getInputStream());
        try (DataInputStream d = new DataInputStream(in)) {
            String fileName = d.readUTF();
            //   System.out.println(fileName);


            File f4 = new File(fileName);
            if (f4.exists()) {
                f4.delete();
            }
            Files.copy(d, Paths.get(fileName));
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(App_window.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [The try-with-resources Statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html), when getting out of block `try (DataInputStream d = new DataInputStream(in)) ...`   the `DataInputStream` `d` will be closed.

[DataInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html) implements [Closable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Closeable.html) with `close()`defined as `Closes this stream and releases any system resources associated with it.`

Hence, `InputStream` gets from `server.getInputStream()` will be closed as well. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14040397/will-closing-a-datainputstream-also-close-the-fileinputstream).

So, to keep sending data, don't close any stream. Just use `try{}catch{}` not `try(...){}catch{}`.

Edit: Socket by default will be kept alive util calling `close()` from clients or server.